# Edit video Metadata without losing quality

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, metadata, exif

I want to edit video metadata (mp4, mkv in x264) on linux  without losing quality. ffmpeg re-encode the video, I don't want that. Is there a solution or an another program ?

This is my solution actually :

```
ffmpeg -i VIDEO_IN -vcodec copy -acodec copy -metadata title="$title" VIDEO_OUT
```

Comment: What's wrong with your example command? It should not re-encode.